# Beautiful Soup text inside a tag

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, tags

I am trying to use BeautifulSoup to query a web page but having some issues. I've opened the web page and read the html, using

```
html1 = urllib.request.urlopen(var).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html1,'html.parser')
```

when I print soup I get a whole mish mash of text, which I guess is normal....

What I now want to do is find the specific part of the text relevant to my goal. I noticed that the sections (tags) I am interested in begin with the letters "br /".

I added the following code to try and get the text inside this "br /":

```
tags1 = soup('br')

for tag in tags1:
    tag.get('br', None)
    print(tag)
```

But the output just seems to be the tags themselves, rather than the text inside those tags.

I'd be really grateful for any suggestions on how to grab that text.  Apologies if this  is a very basic question.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the text from a tag, use `tag.text`:

```
found_tags = soup.find_all('br')

for tag in found_tags:
    print(tag.text)
```